# Airflow Installation on Windows using Docker: invalid variable name "-e \"AIRFLOW_UID"

Tags: docker, airflow

I am new to this, and also a newbie when it comes to cmdline/UNIX syntax.
I am following the instructions on the airflow website to set up via Docker.

After setting env --- **echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)\nAIRFLOW_GID=0" > .env** --- to persist env variables on windows I ran **docker-compose up airflow-init** but it throws an error: **invalid variable name "-e "AIRFLOW_UID"**

I have searched through existing threads and answers and it didn't help me, could anyone please help!?

Answer (score 2):

The id command doesnt work on cmd so for the same reason that fails for you.
[image]

As suggested by @jarek-potiuk try the same command on wsl2 as below -
[image]

Type `wsl` or `wsl -d <DistributionName>`
[image]

Comment: Thanks Sujay. I am new to this as well. How did you access the dockeradmin@dockerdesktop in your 2nd window? I installed WSL2 and windows terminal, but do not know how to enter docker desktop and execute the commands from there.

Comment: Dont get confused with the `dockerdesktop` - its just the hostname i set for the VM on Azure. you may type wsl on your windows terminal. I have updated the image in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing the command on `cmd` or `powershell`?

Answer (score 0):

Those instructions are for Bash and WSL2.

If you want to run Airflow on Windows, you should install WSL2 and run your docker-compose there.

Airflow does not have a Windows support to quick-start or develop it. Officially it only works on Linux, MacOS and WSL2 on Windows.